# При выводе таблицы через datagridview выводит навигационное поле как один из столбцов. как это убрать или добавить название команды к каждому игроку?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Хочу вывести таблицу игроков, но вместе со столбцами выводится навигационное поле, как его убрать или добавить вывод команд к каждому игроку?

```
class Player
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    public Player()
    {
        Teams = new List<Team> ();
    }
}
class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Coach { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
    public Team()
    {
        Players = new List<Player> ();
    }
}

public partial class Soccer_Players : Form
{
    SoccerContext db;

    public Soccer_Players()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        db = new SoccerContext();
        db.Players.Load();
        db.Teams.Load();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = db.Players.Local.ToBindingList();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _Player plForm = new _Player();
        List<Team> teams = db.Teams.ToList();
        plForm.listBox1.DataSource = teams;
        plForm.listBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
        plForm.listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        DialogResult result = plForm.ShowDialog(this);
        if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
            return;
        Player player = new Player();
        player.Age = (int)plForm.numericUpDown1.Value;
        player.Name = plForm.textBox1.Text;
        teams.Clear();
        foreach (var item in plForm.listBox1.SelectedItems)
        {
            teams.Add((Team)item);
        }
        player.Teams = teams;
        db.Players.Add(player);
        db.SaveChanges();
        MessageBox.Show("Новый игрок добавлен");
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count < 1)
            return;
        int index = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
        int id = 0;
        bool converted = Int32.TryParse(dataGridView1[0, index].Value.ToString(), out id);
        if (converted == false)
            return;
        Player player = db.Players.Find(id);
        _Player plForm = new _Player();
        plForm.numericUpDown1.Value = player.Age;
        plForm.textBox1.Text = player.Name; 
        List<Team> teams = db.Teams.ToList();
        plForm.listBox1.DataSource = teams;
        plForm.listBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
        plForm.listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        foreach (Team t in player.Teams)
            plForm.listBox1.SelectedItem = t;
        DialogResult result = plForm.ShowDialog(this);
        if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
            return;
        player.Age = (int)plForm.numericUpDown1.Value;
        player.Name = plForm.textBox1.Text;
        foreach (var team in teams)
        {
            if (plForm.listBox1.SelectedItems.Contains(team))
            {
                if (!player.Teams.Contains(team))
                    player.Teams.Add(team);
            }
            else
            {
                if (player.Teams.Contains(team))
                    player.Teams.Remove(team);
            }
        }
        db.Entry(player).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        MessageBox.Show("Информация обновлена");
    }
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count < 1)
            return;
        int index = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
        int id = 0;
        bool converted = Int32.TryParse(dataGridView1[0, index].Value.ToString(), out id);
        if (converted == false)
            return;
        Player player = db.Players.Find(id);
        db.Players.Remove(player);
        db.SaveChanges();
        MessageBox.Show("Футболист удален");
    }
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _Team tmForm = new _Team();
        DialogResult result = tmForm.ShowDialog(this);
        if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
            return;
        Team team = new Team();
        team.Name = tmForm.textBox1.Text;
        team.Coach = tmForm.textBox2.Text;
        team.Players = new List<Player>();
        db.Teams.Add(team);
        db.SaveChanges();
        MessageBox.Show("Новая команда добавлена");
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что такое навигационное поле? Полоса прокрутки? Так сделайте окно шире. В каком виде вы хотите выводить команды?

Comment: У вас что, один игрок может одновременно в нескольких командах состоять?

Comment: В классе `Player` вместо `ICollection<Team> Teams` должно быть `Team Team`, не?

Comment: тз реализовать связь многие-ко многим, да один игрок может быть в разных командах

Comment: DataGridView не поддерживает напрямую связанные сущности. Декорируйте навигационное свойство атрибутом [Browsable(false) и в этом случае оно не будет отображаться в таблице, но это не решит Вашу проблему. Приведите Ваш набор данных к DataTable.

Comment: [Databinding with WinForms](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/databinding/winforms) - полностью рабочее пошаговое руководство.

Comment: Тут у вас схема Master-Detail. Одним датагридом не обойтись. В одном гриде выводятся игроки, во втором - команды. Код в руководстве по ссылке работает. Попробуйте его реализовать и возвращайтесь с _конкретными_ вопросами.